# Getting an angular is not defined reference

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a calculator app in javascript. I am trying to display the selected operator between the 2 input boxes. However, I am getting an error saying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

This is what the index.html file looks like:

```
<html ng-app="CalculatorApp" lang="en">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<head>
  <title> Cacluclator app</title>


</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="CalculatorCtrl as ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input1"/>

  <span ng-bind="ctrl.selectedOperation"></span>

    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input2"/>

  <button>=</button>
  <p>
    choose operation:
    <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('+')">+</button>
    <button>-</button>
    <button>*</button>
    <button>/</button>

  </p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what the app.js file looks like:

```
'use strict';

// The line below is where the error is showing
var myApp = angular.module('CalculatorApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'CalculatorApp.view1',
  'CalculatorApp.view2',
  'CalculatorApp.version'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);


myApp.controller("CalculatorCtrl",CalculatorCtrl);

function CalculatorCtrl(){
    this.placeholder= function () {
        this.selectedOperation="+";

    }
}
```

I've tried to look at other solutions and it just says that app.js should be below angular.min.js(which is currently empty).

Here is a picture of how the directories look:
[image of directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EQfY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your angular script needs to be loaded before you can use angular.module(). Verify once your angular.min file else try loading it from

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```